# paperclip error while displaying images

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, public-activity

i get an error

```
undefined method `photo' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000004ad42e8>
```

my posts.index.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag @post.photo.url(:small) %>
```

gives me the above error and if i iterate

```
<% @post.each do |image| %>
<%= image_tag image.photo.url %>
<% end %>
```

i get this new error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: position: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"   ORDER BY position ASC
```

here is my model, post.rb

```
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
require 'digest/md5'
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png",
:path => ":rails_root/public/assets/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
include PublicActivity::Model
tracked
```

end
and my posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
def index
    #@hotels = hotels.new()
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")  

    @post = Post.order('position ASC')
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @picture }
end
end
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @picture }
end
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @picture }
end
end
def create
    #@post = Post.create( user_params )
    @post = Post.new(params[:posts].permit(:hotels, :photo, :number, :price, :guest_house, :restaurant,:lodges, :description, :region))
    if @post.save
        redirect_to(:controller => 'homes',:action=> 'index')
    else
        render('new')
    end
end
def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.update_attributes()
end
def delete
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
#def user_params
#params.require(:post).permit(:photo)
#end

end
```

i also have the public activity gem installed on my app and when i try to display the photos using

```
<%= link_to activity.trackable.photo %>
```

i get a link to where the photo was saved but not the actual image as shown below. help me out [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ah I finally realized my mistake. i used the link_to tag instead of the image_tag